# How to save and display an image using core data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to save an image taken with the app to core data and then display it in a UITableView. I have written some code I think should work, but it isn't. Thank you in advance!

Here is the code to save the image:

```
- (void)saveImage {

//    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.thumbImage)];
//    
//    [managedObjectContext setValue:imageData forKey:@"imageData"];
//    
//    NSLog(@"Saved to CoreData");

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    TimeTravelFeed *timeTravelFeed = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TimeTravelFeed" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbImage, 0.8f);

    [timeTravelFeed setValue:imageData forKey:@"imageData"];

}
```

Here is were I am displaying it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PhotoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    TimeTravelFeed *feed = [timeTravelFeeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSData *data = feed.imageData;

    self.feedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.thumbImage = self.feedImage;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Not enough information. What is not working? First check you can save and retrieve the image, then check if you can display an image in a table view, then if you can display it from Core Data.

Comment: The images don't appear in the table view, and how would I check if I the image is saving? (I'm really new to CoreData) @Mundi

Comment: Please don't save the image data in core data, you save image on the disk and save the path of the image in core data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

First, as has been pointed out, you are not calling `[context save:nil]`.

Second, your cell does not seem to have an image view, just an image. This is not very transparent. Presumably, the cell is responsible for assigning the `feedImage` property to some image view. It is better to give the `PhotoCell` an image view property and fill it with

```
cell.imageView.image = imageRetrieved;
```

Third, in the cell you first assign the converted image to some class variable (`self.feedImage`). This is not logical and completely unnecessary. Instead use a variable with local scope or just assign the image to the image view directly.

Finally, you should not really store large blobs (photos) in Core Data. It is recommended that you only store small images, such as thumbnails. For larger files, you should store the path in the Core Data entity and the image files in the documents directory. This can also be accomplished automatically by checking "Allow External Storage" for this attribute in the model editor.

Additional recommendation: do the conversion in the `NSManagedObject` subclass so you do not have to concern your controllers with this technicality.

Comment: Thank you this worked great! First, I was wondering how to make new items appear at the top of the table, not the bottom. Second, I was wondering how to make the table refresh when the Image has been added to Core Data because just putting [tableView reloadData]; in saveImage doen't refresh the table, only when I re-run the app does the image appear

Comment: The proper way is to implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods. See  Apple boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like you've successfully saved your image. Try adding this to saveImage

```
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Some error", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```